# How can the free amino acid B be enantioslectively synthesitzed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, amino-acids

I would like to know how this reaction actually works. I think its an ring metathesis, espececially with the Grubbs catalysator II. But I dont know how to this reaction examole really works especially with respect to enantioselectivity. 
May anyone help? 
[image]

Comment: Which bit do you not understand. The alkylations or the metathesis?

Comment: @Waylander seems to me that it's the diastereoselectivity of the alkylation(s).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the stereoselectivity is completely unimportant as you're doing a double allylation at the same position.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is a homework type question. Yet, I have some concern of this being a exam question, probably one already taken. So I give a step by step answer depicted in following diagram (courtesy of https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/sketcher/):

[image: Amino Acid B.jpg]

Comment: I don't actually agree: in step (b) the reaction proceeds via an enolate, which destroys the preexisting stereochemistry, and the alkylation will again occur anti to the t-butyl group. So it is the allyl group and not the homoallyl group which ends up on the top face.

Comment: @ orthocresol: I agree with you 100%. However, OP didn't give final structure so I gave him what possible logical answer for him/her. I might have to use ChemDraw to do proper explanation, which I don't have an access during the weekend. :-)